# ElasticSearch NEST term query returns no results

Tags: c#, database, elasticsearch, nest

Here my schema

```
[ElasticType(Name = "importFile")]
public class ImportFile : DocumentMapping
{
    [ElasticProperty(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

I made a NEST query like this one:

```
    var res = ElasticClient.Search<ImportFile>(s => s
        .Index(ElasticIndexName)
        .Filter(f =>
            f.Term(t => t.FileName, "Group-1.uhh"))).Documents.ToArray();
```

and returns zero elements!

If I peek inside the db (using postman) I can see my documents:

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 14.069489,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "reviewer-bdd-test-index",
        "_type": "importFile",
        "_id": "AU9kUka2hr5Jg98UXOae",
        "_score": 14.069489,
        "_source": {
          "fileName": "Group-1.uhh",
          "groupId": "0ae1206d0644eabd82ae490e612732df5da2cd141fdee70dc64207f86c96094f",
          "filePath": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "reviewer-bdd-test-index",
        "_type": "importFile",
        "_id": "AU9kZO25hr5Jg98UXRnk",
        "_score": 14.069489,
        "_source": {
          "fileName": "group-1.uhh",
          "groupId": "0ae1206d0644eabd82ae490e612732df5da2cd141fdee70dc64207f86c96094f",
          "filePath": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may not have explicitly put a mapping for the type into the index *before* indexing your documents, so Elasticsearch has inferred the mapping based on the default mappings for fields in the documents it has seen. As an example, given the following type

```
[ElasticType(Name = "importFile")]
public class ImportFile
{
    [ElasticProperty(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

if we index some documents as follows

```
void Main()
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));            
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    client.Index<ImportFile>(
        new ImportFile{
            FileName = "Group-1.uhh",
            FilePath = "",
            GroupId = "0ae1206d0644eabd82ae490e612732df" + 
                      "5da2cd141fdee70dc64207f86c96094"
        },
        index => index
            .Index("reviewer-bdd-test-index")
            .Type("importFile")
            .Refresh());

    client.Index<ImportFile>(
        new ImportFile
        {
            FileName = "group-1.uhh",
            FilePath = "",
            GroupId = "0ae1206d0644eabd82ae490e612732df" + 
                      "5da2cd141fdee70dc64207f86c96094"
        },
        index => index
            .Index("reviewer-bdd-test-index")
            .Type("importFile")
            .Refresh());

    var results = client.Search<ImportFile>(s => s
                .Index("reviewer-bdd-test-index")
                .Type("importFile")
                .Query(q => q
                   .Filtered(fq => fq
                        .Filter(f => f
                            .Term(p => p.FileName, "Group-1.uhh")
                        )
                    )
                )
            );

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", results.RequestInformation.RequestMethod, results.RequestInformation.RequestUrl));
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(results.RequestInformation.Request)); 
    Console.WriteLine("Matching document count: {0}", results.Documents.Count());
}
```

the following is output in the console

```
POST http://localhost:9200/reviewer-bdd-test-index/importFile/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "fileName": "Group-1.uhh"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
Matching document count: 0
```

We get no matching documents. Checking the mapping in Elasticsearch with

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/reviewer-bdd-test-index/_mapping"
```

We see that the mapping for the type `importFile` is

```
{
   "reviewer-bdd-test-index": {
      "mappings": {
         "importFile": {
            "properties": {
               "fileName": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "groupId": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which is not what we expect; both `fileName` and `groupId` should also have `"index": "not_analyzed"` and `filePath` is not even in the mapping. Both of these are because Elasticsearch has inferred the mapping based on the documents it has been passed - `fileName` and `groupId` have been mapped as string types and will have undergone analysis with the standard analyzer, and *I believe* `filePath` has not been mapped because both seen documents had an empty string value for the field, so the **[standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)** applied to the field would not produce any tokens for the inverted index, hence the field is not included in the mapping.

So, to ensure that things work as expected, we need to add a mapping to the index before indexing any documents

```
void Main()
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    // Add the mapping for ImportFile to the index
    client.CreateIndex(indexSelector => indexSelector
        .Index("reviewer-bdd-test-index")
        .AddMapping<ImportFile>(mapping => mapping
            .MapFromAttributes()
        )
    );

    // ... Same as above after this point
}
```

Which results in

```
POST http://localhost:9200/reviewer-bdd-test-index/importFile/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "fileName": "Group-1.uhh"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
Matching document count: 1
```

**Success!** We have a matching document. Checking the mapping in Elasticsearch yields what we expect

```
{
   "reviewer-bdd-test-index": {
      "mappings": {
         "importFile": {
            "properties": {
               "fileName": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "filePath": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "store": true
               },
               "groupId": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Additionally, the attribute mapping could be replaced with the fluent mapping instead

```
var indexResult = client.CreateIndex(indexDescriptor => indexDescriptor
    .Index("reviewer-bdd-test-index")
    .AddMapping<ImportFile>(mapping => mapping
        .Type("importFile")
        .MapFromAttributes()
        .Properties(properties => properties
            .String(s => s
                .Name(file => file.FileName)
                .Store(false)
                .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))
            .String(s => s
                .Name(file => file.GroupId)
                .Store(false)
                .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))
            .String(s => s
                .Name(file => file.FilePath)
                .Store(true))
        )
    )
);
```

Either attribute mapping or fluent mapping will do at this point however, there are some things that can only be achieved with fluent mappings such as **[multi_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html?q=multi_field)**.