# ElasticSearch Nest Nuget. Requested extensions.cs on connection

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I followed the documentation on getting started and connecting to the ElasticSearch node. We have that installed and working perfectly, with Marvel and Kibana.

I have setup the very basic connection and am trying to index a person as detailed in the guide.

```
        var node = new Uri("http://******:9200");
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var person = new Person
        {
            Id = "1",
            Firstname = "Martijn",
            Lastname = "Laarman"
        };

        var index = client.Index(person);
```

When I executed the application it said it couldnt find externsions.cs. I couldnt find it in the packagaes so canceled it. Now its is throwing the following exception:

```
at Nest.Extensions.ThrowIfNull[T](T value, String name) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\Extensions\Extensions.cs:line 101
   at Nest.IndexPathInfo.Update[T](ElasticsearchPathInfo`1 pathInfo, IIndexRequest`1 request) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\DSL\IndexDescriptor.cs:line 21
   at Nest.IndexDescriptor`1.UpdatePathInfo(IConnectionSettingsValues settings, ElasticsearchPathInfo`1 pathInfo) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\DSL\IndexDescriptor.cs:line 52
   at Nest.BaseRequest`1.ToPathInfo(IConnectionSettingsValues settings, TParameters queryString) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\DSL\Common\BaseRequest.cs:line 45
   at Nest.BaseRequest`1.Nest.IPathInfo<TParameters>.ToPathInfo(IConnectionSettingsValues settings) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\DSL\Common\BaseRequest.cs:line 66
   at Nest.ElasticClient.Nest.IHighLevelToLowLevelDispatcher.Dispatch[D,Q,R](D descriptor, Func`3 dispatch) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ElasticClient.cs:line 73
   at Nest.ElasticClient.Index[T](T object, Func`2 indexSelector) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Index.cs:line 17
   at IDENTElectricSearchMinion.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\cmbrown\Desktop\Development Source Files\IDENTElectricSearchMinion\IDENTElectricSearchMinion\Program.cs:line 28
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The nuget install seemed to complete sucessfully and if I navigate to the server url I get back:

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "****",
  "cluster_name" : "***search",
  "version" : {
     "number" : "1.7.1",
     "build_hash" : "b88f43fc40b0bcd7f173a1f9ee2e97816de80b19",
     "build_timestamp" : "2015-07-29T09:54:16Z",
     "build_snapshot" : false,
     "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

UPDATE:

Found you need to specify the index with the connection string as follows:

```
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://****:9200"))
        .SetDefaultIndex("persons")
```

Comment: alternatively, instead of relying on the default index, define a mapping for the type upfront. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204858/elasticsearch-nest-term-query-returns-no-results/32311020#32311020 as an example